# Case Sensitivity in Login Form C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

My Login Form is functioning, however when I input the username with an uppercase in the first letter of the word and the username that is in my database are all lowercase still it allows to access and Login is successful.

Can you help me to fix this?
I really need your help .

This is my current code

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {





                if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Input Required Fields!",
            "Note",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                }

                else
                {

                    //Passing the value from textbox
                    Tic_Tac_Toe frm2 = new Tic_Tac_Toe(textBox1.Text);
                    View view = new View(textBox1.Text);

                    string str = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Majel\Tic Tac Toe\Database\Database.mdb";

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str);
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE Users = '" + textBox1.Text + "' AND Pass = '" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);

                    con.Open(); try
                    {
                        int i;

                        i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!",
this.Hide();
                        frm2.Show();


                    }


                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Name or Password",
        "Note",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

                    }

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }

                finally
                {

                    con.Close();

                }
            }
        }
```

Can someone help me out? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause to your SQL which restricts the change to your logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, you need a `WHERE` clause.

> string SqlString = "Update data SET Player1 =?,Player2 =? WHERE
>   UserName=@user";

Without it, the update applies to all rows in the table. Note that this works exactly the same with a DELETE statement.

Now you wouldn't generally match on a user name like that, you would use the tables primary key for these kinds of comparisons. Beyond that, this is SQL 101. I would strongly suggest getting a RDBMS book and learn the basics of SQL before trying to continue much further.

Answer (score 1):

I can say you for save passwords in db, you must save password Data with Hashing `Algorithm` such as `MD5` or `SHA1`
When user type password for login you hash string that typed for password and compare this string with password that save in db

```
    public static void HashPassword(string Password, out string Salt, out string Hash)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        byte[] s = new byte[20];
        rnd.NextBytes(s);
        Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(s);
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding u = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] pass = u.GetBytes(Password);
        byte[] all = new byte[pass.Length + s.Length];
        Array.Copy(pass, all, pass.Length);
        Array.Copy(s, 0, all, pass.Length, s.Length);
        Byte[] H = sha.ComputeHash(all);
        Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(H);
    }

    public bool IsPasswordCorrect(string Password, string Salt, string Hash)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed();
        byte[] s = Convert.FromBase64String(Salt);
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding u = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] pass = u.GetBytes(Password);
        byte[] all = new byte[pass.Length + s.Length];
        Array.Copy(pass, all, pass.Length);
        Array.Copy(s, 0, all, pass.Length, s.Length);
        Byte[] H = sha.ComputeHash(all);
        return (Hash == Convert.ToBase64String(H));
    }
```

now you must use `HashPassword` method to give hash an salt and  save hash and salt to db for every user.
When want to check password use `IsPasswordcorrect` Method

for your code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Input Required Fields!",
            "Note",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                }

                else
                {

                    //Passing the value from textbox
                    Tic_Tac_Toe frm2 = new Tic_Tac_Toe(textBox1.Text);
                    View view = new View(textBox1.Text);

                    string str = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Majel\Tic Tac Toe\Database\Database.mdb";

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str);
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM data WHERE Users = '" + textBox1.Text, con);
                    OleDbDataAdapter ta=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
                     try
                    {
                    ta.Fill(ds);
                    if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count==0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("User Dos not Exists");
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
                    string hash=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"].ToString();
                    string salt=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["salt"].ToString();
                         if(IsPasswordCorrect(textBox2.Text,salt,hash))
                         {
                             MessageBox.Show("Success");

                        this.Hide();
                        frm2.Show();


                    }


                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Name or Password",
        "Note",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

                    }

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }

                finally
                {

                    con.Close();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you provide example sir?

Comment: @ Mehdi Haghshena,If you would mind sir,I just wanna ask if  how to use it in my codes above? can you provide it sir? Actually, it's too complicated for me, Im just a newbie in c#.

Comment: please check I change your code but not test it you may forced to debug it,  
please be careful

Comment: ,Sir there's an error here **string hash=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"];
                    string salt=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["salt"];** It say,**Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'.An explicit conversion exists(are you a missing a cast?)**, sir what shall I do?

Comment: string hash=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"].ToString();